# Log-Log graphic : calculate point B.x, with point A, the slope and B.y

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, slope

I want to plot the segment [AB] on a log-log graph.
I have the point A, the slope and B.y.
How to find B.x?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a function y= f(x), on log-log paper by  marking a point x on the horizontal axis and and y on the vertica axis we are actually marking log(x) and log(y) so that a linear graph, instead of giving "y= mx+ b", gives log(y)= m log(x)+ b and,taking the exponential of both sides y= Bx^m where B= e^b.

If you have a point, (Ax,Ay) and slope m the we have log(Ay)= m log(Ax)+ b so b= log(Ay)- log(Ax)= log(Ay/Ax) so that e^b= Ay/Ax.

So y= (Ay/Ax)x^m.  If y= By then we have By= (Ay/Ax)x^m so that x^m= AxBy/Ay so that $Bx= x= \sqrt[m]{AxBy/Ay}$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.